# Yarn watch won't start

Tags: symfony, yarnpkg

I'm currently working on a Symfony project and following a tutorial on symfonycasts.com. However, when I run the `yarn watch` command, I'm encountering the following error:

```
Error: Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured is not a recognized property or method.
  
  - index.js:969 Object.get
    [mixed_vynil]/[@symfony]/webpack-encore/index.js:969:27
  
  - webpack.config.js:5 Object.<anonymous>
    /Users/simondrohsen/mixed_vynil/webpack.config.js:5:13
  
  - loader:1097 Module._compile
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14
  
  - loader:1149 Object.Module._extensions..js
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10
  
  - loader:975 Module.load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32
  
  - loader:822 Function.Module._load
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12
  
  - loader:999 Module.require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19
  
  - helpers:102 require
    node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18
  
  - webpack-cli.js:204 WebpackCLI.tryRequireThenImport
    [mixed_vynil]/[webpack-cli]/lib/webpack-cli.js:204:22
  
  - webpack-cli.js:1404 loadConfigByPath
    [mixed_vynil]/[webpack-cli]/lib/webpack-cli.js:1404:38

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I've tried to analyze the problem but I'm not sure what is causing the error. It seems that the method or property Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured is not recognized.

Can someone help me identify the issue and suggest a solution? I've already installed Symfony version 5.5.6 and Webpack version 5.88.1, checked all the dependencies, and ran yarn install. Is there anything else I should check or change to get `yarn watch` working?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!